# Bash replace lines in file that contain functions

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script that contains the following line

```
PROC_ID=$(cat myfile.sh | grep running)
```

which, after you echo out the value would be 1234 or something like that.

What I want to do is find and replace instances of this line with a literal value

I want to replace it with `PROC_ID=1234` instead of having the function call.

I've tried doing this in another shell script using `sed` but I can't get it to work

```
STR_TO_USE="PROC_ID=${1}"
STR_TO_REP='PROC_ID=$(cat myfile.sh | grep running)'

sed -i "s/$STR_TO_REP/$STR_TO_USE/g" sample.sh
```

but it complains stating `sed: 1: "sample.sh": unterminated substitute pattern`

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
sample.sh should contain beforehand

```
#!/bin/bash
....

PROC_ID=$(cat myfile.sh | grep running)
echo $PROC_ID

....
```

After, it should contain

```
#!/bin/bash
....

PROC_ID=1234
echo $PROC_ID

....
```

The script I'm using as described above will be taking the in an arg from the command line, hence `STR_TO_USE="PROC_ID=${1}"`

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
sed /^PROC_ID=/s/=.*/=1234/
```

Translation:

- At line begining by `PROC_ID=`
- replace `=` to end of line by `=1234`.

or more accurate

```
sed '/^[ \o11]*PROC_ID=.*myfile.*running/s/=.*/=1234/'
```

could be enough

- (`[ \o11]*` mean *some spaces and or tabs could even prepand*)

Comment: This works, with the exception that if `PROC_ID` isn't at the start of the line, it fails (ie is poorly formatted and has a space or two)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, I want to point out something obvious. This: `$(cat myfile.sh | grep running)` will at the very least NOT only contain the string `1234` but will certainly also contain the string `running`. But since you aren't asking for help with that, I'll leave it alone.

All you need in your above sed, is first to backslash the `$`.

```
STR_TO_REP='PROC_ID=\$(cat myfile.sh | grep running)'
```

This allows the sed command to be terminated.